# Using the same JDBC connection across multiple calls to Spring Boot REST API

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jdbc

I have a REST web service written in Java/Spring boot and running on Tomcat 9.

I need to create a MySQL temporary table in one web service call and access it later in another service call. As temporary tables are connection scoped, I need to use the same connection used to create the table during the first call in the "select" query in the second call.

The problem is that Tomcat manages JDBC connections in a connection pool. In the second service call,whenever I create a JDBC connection, any connection from the pool can be picked up. In this case, the temporary table will not be visible.

My question is: how can I pick the same connection from the connection pool? Is there any kind of id/tag that distinguishes them?

Comment: I'd suggest finding another way to do this. This would only work if you keep the connection open and associated with the HTTP session until you're done with it. That can seriously impact the scalability of your application. I'd suggest using a *permanent* table, with data associated to your HTTP session using some kind of unique identifier, and something to expunge outdated data.

Comment: Permanent tables are not feasable in my application. On heavy service load, The database will end up with a lot of strange permanent temporary tables. Naming these tables uniquely is another problem. Expunging is yet more problematic. It is difficult to know when to do that. MySQL temporary tables solve all these problems.

Comment: You can use a *single* permanent table (maybe two for some housekeeping information), where entries are keyed to the HTTP session. You just need to clean up after the process is done, and have a scavenger thread to clean up entries that weren't cleaned up normally.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, But it's nontrivial to detect when the session is truly done. I agree that using non-temporary tables is difficult for this application.

Comment: @BillKarwin That depends on whether or not the data is tied to the HTTP session as such, or just to a unit-of-work that spans multiple HTTP requests. If the latter, there should be a clearly defined end, and you'll just need a scavenger for things terminated mid-way through.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel There is no clearly defined end. A user may stay in the interface (a web page) for un undetermined period of time, sending multiple HTTP requests. Maybe a timeout of 30 or 60 minutes is the most logical expunge technique. I personally don't like the idea of relying on a thread to cleanup in a Spring REST service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would not help even if you could ensure that the "same" connection is used on subsequent requests, because part of allocating a connection from the pool involves resetting things related to session state.

This is by design and it's a good thing, because otherwise you could leak private data from one database session to another unrelated session. That would be a problem for example if one user stored some sensitive data in a temporary table, and then that temp table were readable by another user's database session. Likewise for things like unfinished transactions, session variables, and connection character set. All of these are reset when a connection is doled out by the pool.

So if you use temporary tables, you should use them only during the same request, because they will be dropped when you are done using that connection.

If you need to use data from one request to the next request, you can:

- Store data in a non-temporary table.
- Store data in a cache.
- Write background service in Java to process the data, so you have code creating and using the temp tables, running asynchronously to the requests. This is a lot more work, and probably overkill for a simple web app, but there are some services where it's the best solution.

Comment: I think that the only reasonable solution is the cache. The background service is complex and adds a lot of weakness to the application imho. It may become a bottleneck later.

Comment: @AhmadWabbi Yes, that's what I would choose too, in most cases. I recommend [Redis](https://redis.io/) or [Memcached](https://www.memcached.org/) as a cache server.